# Which notation is wise to consdier?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, notation

Consider that $f(x)$ is a continuous function on the **closed** interval $\left[ a,b \right]$. Also, its $n$-th derivative is continuous on $\left( a,b \right)$ where $n$ is any desired integer. I mean that $f$ is infinitely differentiable. Now I want to say that $f(x)$ satisfies a second order differential equation on some interval with some boundary conditions. I give an example. Which of the following is correct to write down? 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} + f =0 &\hbox{on $[a,b]$}\\
f(a)=1 \\
f'(b)=0
\end{array}
\right. \tag{1}
$$
or
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} + f =0 &\hbox{on $(a,b)$}\\
f(a)=1 \\
f'(b)=0
\end{array}
\right. \tag{2}
$$

**My thought**

I think $(2)$ is correct as the derivatives are not defined at the end points $a$ and $b$. If we accept this thought what does it mean to say $f'(b) = 0$. I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you should use (2). Your system does not require $f$ to be differentiable at $a$, although some regularity result will imply this conclusion *after* a solution has been found. Of course the request $f'(b)=1$ understands that $f$ must be differentiable (in some suitable sense) at $b$.

Comment: What do you mean by " f(x) must be differentiable **in some suitable sense**  at b " ?

Comment: Can we prove **without** solving the equation that $f(x)$ must also be differentiable at $a$.

Comment: I mean that standard differentiation is not always the best idea of differentiation. For differential equations one could also consider weakly differentiable solutions.

Comment: Maybe I should take the course, **Theory of ODEs**!  :)

Answer (score 1):

First, we can talk about direction derivatives in $\Bbb R$, and that's what usually understood when you are dealing with closed intervals. In that sense, both equations make sense, and even have the same solution whenever you force $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$, otherwise $(2)$ does not imply anything about values of $f$ at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: In which class are you looking for the solution?